# CSS Text Input field not aligning top left?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have an Input Text Field display the text on the top left, right now the text is centered vertically and horizontally in the middle.

```
<input class="userInput" type="text">
<style>
.userInput {
text-align: left;
margin: 1px;
padding: 1px;
width: 500px;
height: 300px;
vertical-align: top;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Text inputs are for single line input. I would suggest using  `<textarea>` instead.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/z58vy354/

Answer (score 2):

As other have suggested to use textarea instead of input field but you if don't wanna it to look like textarea or stretchable, you can use style `resize:none;` on it.

Answer (score 1):

you should use textarea instead of input try this code:

```
<textarea rows="20" cols="50">
Test
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Target the input's placeholder

```css
.userInput::placeholder {
    text-align: left;
}
```