# input tag bigger size and text in input tag centered vertically but placeholder not

Tags: html, css, input, alignment, placeholder

I want that the placeholder is on the Top-Left in the Input field.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6y2mX.png

But when i click into the Input field and write text it is centered.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/96a0R.png

Comment: That is a large input field. They are used for one-line input, maybe you are looking for a textarea? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34027368/css-text-input-field-not-aligning-top-left

Comment: Use ::input-placeholder {text-align: left;} **not** ::-webkit-input-placeholder {text-align: left;}   See https://codepen.io/tamjk/pen/qBrpzpd